# Using Keyboard View as an app

Tags: android

It is possible to program normally "inside the keyboard"?

My idea was to put a clickable circle in the middle of the keyboard... Is it possible??

I'm new on android programming, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean writing your own keyboard?  Then sure, you can do whatever you want.  You won't use KeyboardView though-  its too limiting, to add custom stuff to the middle of it you'd want to implement your own view.

If you mean adding it programmatically to either the default or a 3rd party keyboard-  nope.  That part of the screen is owned by the keyboard app and you can't override it.